# Adding paths in random generated world

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm creating a random generated world with libgdx in my game but sometimes the path is blocked. What is the best way to detect blocked path and cut through it?

[This is what it looks like](http://puu.sh/pemi5/b29b66de75.png)

I use simplex noise for the paths. It's really messy for platformers and since there is roof and ground the path is blocked. I need to delete blocks if the path is blocked, but can't find a simple way of doing that.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What situations would this "path cutting" need to take place?

Comment: What is your algorithm for generating the worlds?

Comment: You can float fill one area, if it's done and did not reach a certain point on the map then that part is blocked off. But I'm not sure you are doing yourself a favor using simplex noise to generate a level. Need more information to help you out though.